# Erro na chamada do método Python (list)

Tags: python

Boa tarde!

Estou recebendo um erro de name 'month' is not defined por conta do último método deste código:

```
self.calc_months(month_of_year) 

        def year(self, execution_times):
            return [self.month(execution_times, month)]
```

Comment: Por favor, corrija a indentação do seu código na pergunta; no Python, como deve saber, a indentação é primordial para a interpretação correta. E verificando a implementação do método `year`, de fato o objeto `month` não é definido. Qual valor ele deveria possuir?

Comment: então, ele só pode receber um parâmetro que é o execution_times, esse método year precisa informar a lista com o valor de todos os meses, calculado no método anterior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O exemplo abaixo define a variável `month` em um loop que percorre os 12 meses (1 a 12).

```
def year(self, execution_times):
    return [self.month(execution_times, month) for month in range(1, 13)]
```

Comment: muito obrigada! deu certinho.

Answer (score -1):

Eu reformatei o teu código e criei uma rotina para usar tua classe:

```
cost = CloudCost()

for mes in range(1,12):
    print(cost.month(10, mes))
```

E tudo funcionou normalmente e o método foi invocado:

```
0.387128
0.349664
0.387128
0.37464
0.387128
0.37464
0.387128
0.387128
0.37464
0.387128
0.37464
```

Verifique como está a indentação do teu código.

Comment: obrigada!!  consegui submeter o código!